# Given $ [ h_1 \, h_2 \, h_3 ] = \lambda A [ r_1 \, r_2 \, t] $, prove that $h_1^TA^{-T}A^{-1}h_2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

$r_1, r_2$ are orthonormal column vectors, $\lambda$ is an arbitrary scaler and A is a 3*3 upper triangular matrix, $A^{-T} = (A^{-1})^{T}$. This equation comes from [a paper on camera calibration(page 4 and 5)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/zhang/Papers/TR98-71.pdf).
My solution: Let 
$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \\
A_2 \\
A_3
\end{bmatrix} $
,we get 
$ \overrightarrow{h_1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \cdot r_1 \\
A_2 \cdot r_1 \\
A_3 \cdot r_1
\end{bmatrix},
\overrightarrow{h_2} =
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 \cdot r_2 \\
A_2 \cdot r_2 \\
A_3 \cdot r_2
\end{bmatrix}
$
And then simplify $h_1^TA^{-T}A^{-1}h_2$ as $h_1^T(AA^T)^{-1}h_2$. What property of $(AA^T)^{-1}$ can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ are orthonormal (and hence orthogonal), so their dot product is zero.

Solve for $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\mathbf{r}_2$ in terms of $\mathbf{h}_1$, $\mathbf{h}_2$, and $\mathbf{A}$, and the result follows.

$$\mathbf{h}_{1}=\lambda\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}_{1}\quad\implies\quad\mathbf{h}_{1}^{T}=\lambda\mathbf{r}_{1}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{T}\quad\implies\quad\mathbf{r}_{1}^{T}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{h}_{1}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-T}$$

$$\mathbf{h}_{2}=\lambda\mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}_{2}\quad\implies\quad\mathbf{r}_{2}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{h}_{2}$$

$$0=\mathbf{r}_{1}\cdot\mathbf{r}_{2}=\mathbf{r}_{1}^{T}\mathbf{r}_{2}=\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\left(\mathbf{h}_{1}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{h}_{2}\right)\quad\implies\quad\mathbf{h}_{1}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{h}_{2}=0$$